# Stroke path with brush from bottom to top

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, stroke, brush

When stroking a group of separated paths in Photoshop with a brush, the program *paints* from top to bottom, left to right. Is there a way to revert the way from bottom to top?

In the example image, I would like using this sample custom brush over the paths so the visible tips would be the bottom ones instead of the top ones.

[image]

- It's not possible to flip the image vertically since it's an irregular
  shape
- This custom brush is a simple shape to make this question more understandable
- It's a step in an action

Comment: You can't flip the image, but why not simply rotate the canvas 180, paint the stroke, then rotate back?

Comment: @13ruce It's something similar, I put it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got the answer in the Adobe forum

- Make the path from bottom to top

or

- Flip the path horizontal/vertical, stroke the path in an empty layer and flip the layer vertically

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it!